# Rails 4 Authentication with Devise and Omniauth for LinkedIn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I have worked through more than 30 blogs and I'm afraid I haven't found the mis-step or mistake I'm making.

I am trying to setup LinkedIn authentication with my Rails 4 app. It uses devise and omniauth (with omniauth-linkedin-oauth2).

I have a user model that has:

```
  def self.find_for_linkedin_oauth(auth)
   puts auth.info 
   where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name  
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name   
      user.image = auth.info.image 
    end
  end
```

I have omniauth.rb initialiser with:

```
 Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
   provider :linkedin, "key", "secret",
     REDIRECT_URI = 'http://www.homepage.com' #Redirect users after authentication to this path, ensure that you have set up your routes to handle the callbacks
     STATE = [long tricky code] #A unique long string that is not easy to guess
     :scope => "r_basicprofile r_emailaddress", 
     :field => ["id", "email-address", "first-name", "last-name" ],
     :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}} 
 end
```

I have an omniauth_callbacks controller with:

```
 def linkedin
    @user = User.find_for_linkedin_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
      if @user.persisted?
         sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
          set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "LinkedIn") if is_navigational_format?
        else
          session["devise.linkedin_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to root_path
        end
      end
```

I have Facebook set up and working. Unfortunately, I found a blog post that I could follow without learning for Facebook so I'm finding it really difficult to see how to set this up. I haven't understood the code involved to spot any errors. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I struggled as well. Used OAuth2 gem: https://github.com/decioferreira/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2. Relied mostly on this: http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/. Had to change ":linked_in" to ":linkedin". Also had a little help from this: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Managing-Multiple-Providers.